# Switch statement in PHP/javascript returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, undefined

I have this switch statement:

```
var currency = "";

switch (row.currency) {
case 1 :
    currency = "&pound;";
    break;
case 2 :
    currency = " &#36;";
    break;
case 3 :
    currency = "&euro;";
    break;

default:
    currency = "&pound;";
    break;
}
```

Then I try to reference `currency` here:

```
<td>' + currency + '<input class="editinput number" type="text" value="' + row.adhoc_setup_rem_cost + '" name="changes[' + row.id + '][adhoc_setup_rem_cost]" /></td>
```

But when I view it I just get the word 'undefined' before the input box instead of a currency symbol...

Comment: Please show the full code you are using to generate the HTML, including where you assigned a value to `currency`

Comment: Where do you have PHP?

Comment: What is `row.currency`?

Comment: I assigned a value to `currency` in the switch statement. row.currency is a row in my database, the value is always 1, 2 or 3

Comment: @CarlaDessi if `currency` is `undefined` at the point where you generate the HTML, that means that either the switch statement is run after the HTML generation or it is done in a different scope that is not inherited by the HTML generating code (e.g. a function). Can you show the full code block that calls the switch statement and generates the HTML?

Comment: `var txt = document.createTextNode(currency);
document.getElementById('tdID').appendChild(txt);`

Comment: if `row.currency` will always be 1,2 or 3, why not use `var currency = ['&pound;','&pound;','&#36;','&euro;']` and use `currency[row.currency || 0]`. It's a lot shorter than the switch statement

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem sir, can you explain that please, I want to use that syntax too, is that logic inside an array?

Comment: @rps: It's got everything to do with how JS evaluates expressions: `row.currency || 0` is an expression, that needs to be resolved to a singular value, and acts sort of like a loose-camparison ternary (`+(rows.currency) == true ? +(rows.currency) : 0`), so if `+(row.currency)` is `NaN` or 0 (`undefined`, `false` or `''` are impossible), the expression will resolve to `0` (the first element of the array being `&pound;`), the default value. if it's 2, the expression will resolve to that value, ie the index for `&#36;`. That's it, really.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem got it, thanks again, and that unary operator there!!!!, another way to check if a var is a number except 0 right???!

Comment: @rps: sort of, if by _unary operator_ you mean the `+()` that's the same as doing `Number(something)`. It just coerces whatever the variable/property is holding to a number. If you open your console: `+('123');` it'll resolve to `123`, `+('foo')` will result in `NaN`. `+('00')` will be 0, but that's a falsy value, so the right hand operand of the logical operator will be the result of the expression

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what is row.currency here.
But i tried this and it worked fine for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var currency = "";
 var row={currency:1};
 switch (row.currency) {
 case 1 :
         currency = "&pound;";
         break;
 case 2 :
         currency = " &#36;";
         break;
 case 3 :
         currency = "&euro;";
         break;

 default:
         currency = "&pound;";
          break;
 }

 $('<td>'+currency+'<input type="text"> </td>').insertAfter("p");
});
```

so may be it is the problem with your `row.currency`. so check it again or share your code.

Comment: Please: from the JavaScript tag wiki: _"If a library or framework is used, then tag the question with the appropriate tags"_. There is no jQ tag here, so don't post jQ answers

Comment: Elias has a point. Please use pure JS, e.g.[onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and [document.write](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) to print the result. It's ugly but it'll do the job in the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

remove currency from your html code and add this to your script  code after adding an id to the td

```
var txt = document.createTextNode(currency);  
document.getElementById('tdID').appendChild(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to rps, and as an answer to the OP's question, too. I'd avoid using a `switch`, and simply use an array instead. Since `row.currency` will always be 1, 2 or 3, you could easily assign an array holding the corresponding values to `currency`:

```
var currency = ['&pound;','&pound;','&#36;','&euro;'];//default value is 0
//concat into string like so:
'<td>' + currency[+(row.currency) || 0] + '<inp...';
```

What I'm doing here, does assume that the `row.currency`, when coerced to a number, will never yield a value higher than 3, because if it does, you're concatenating `undefined` into the string. To avoid that, simply do this:

```
'<td>' + currency[+(row.currency)] || currency[0] + '<inp...';
```

That way, the expression above will always default to `'&pound;'`. On the whole, though, I must say your code looks strange to me. And that's putting it mildly. You seem to be generating HTML in JavaScript, which is likely going to be run client-side. Generating HTML, when using PHP (as your title suggests you're using PHP) is just far better than whatever you're doing/trying to do at the moment.

Assuming you query a DB using `PDO`

```
$currency = array(1 => '&pound;', 2 => '&#36;', 3 => '&euro;');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $row->currency = isset($currency[$row->currency]) ? $row->currency : 1;//default 1
    echo '<tr><td>'. $currency[$row->currency].'</td>';
}
```

That said, I really can't be sure what the best approach in your case is, as you do need to provide more details: where is the code you posted supposed to run, what is it supposed to do...?

Comment: @rps: You're welcome, and yes, the fiddle is exactly right. IMO, it's the cleanest (easily maintainable: add something to the array, change the values...) and just requires a lot less code than a `switch`